# Errors in c program

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//funkcija dodavanja u red
 void add(cvor* red, int i, cvor broj){ //Errors appear in this line
    red[i] = broj;
}
// brise iz vadi iz reda clan koji je prvi usao
cvor delete(cvor *red, int i){
    cvor a;
    int e;
    a = red[0];
    for (e = 1; e < i;e+=1){
        red[e - 1] = red[e];

    }
    return a;
}
//definiticja strukture cvora
typedef struct temp{
    double info;
    struct temp* levi;
    struct temp* desni;

}cvor;

// pravljenje novog cvora
cvor *novi_cvor(cvor *levi_sin,cvor *desni_sin,double broj){
    cvor *novi = malloc(sizeof(cvor));
    novi->levi = levi_sin;
    novi->desni = desni_sin;
    novi->info = broj;
    return novi;

}

void main(){
    int i=0,e,n;
    cvor *red;
    double broj;
    // definisanje reda kao dinamcikog niza
    red = calloc(50, sizeof(cvor));
    // u red unosimo clanove liste redom

    printf("Uneti broj clanova liste");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    while (n>0){
        scanf_s("%lf", &broj);

        add(red, i, *novi_cvor(NULL,NULL,broj));
        i += 1;
        n -= 1;
    }
    //ispis reda
    for (e = 0; e < i; e += 1){
        printf("%2.lf\n\n", red[e]);
    }



    system("pause");
}
```

These are the errors :

```
Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'  
Error 3 error C2059: syntax error : 'type'  
Error 4 error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

All of these appears in line 4.

Any solutions ?
Thanks

Comment: *Where* do you get the errors? Please mark it out in the posted source.

Comment: your `typedef` move to top.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a struct, a typedef or a method in general in another method, you have to declare it up or write their code up.
It means that when you call your function delete in main, it doesn't detected what cvor means, because cvor is defined below.

Put

```
typedef struct temp{
double info;
struct temp* levi;
struct temp* desni;
}cvor;
```

at first line, before the rest.